# EntityManager is closed by unique key violation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

My application uses the Doctrine2 EntityManager. In a loop I like to insert 5 data sets to different tables.

```
public function insertRate($dateObj, $rate)
{       
    $model = new TestModel();

    $model
        ->setDate($dateObj)
        ->setRate($rate);

    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($model);

    try {
        $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $currentTime = new \DateTime();
        echo 'Duplicate entry <br>' .
            'At Time ' . $currentTime->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "<hr>";
    }
}
```

If maybe insert 2 faild because of an duplicated entry (unique constraint) the following 3 statements will not be executed by the entityManger because the manger is closed.

I use a workaround like this:

```
$currentEm = $this->em;
if (!$currentEm->isOpen()) {
    $this->em = $currentEm->create(
        $currentEm->getConnection(), $currentEm->getConfiguration());
}
```

With this workarround, a new entityManger will be set up but the auto_increment ids are not like 1, 2, 3... but 1, 5, 10, 15...

I dont want to check if there can be a unique constraint violation because of the additional selects.

How can I fix this, and is this workarround ok?

Comment: can you show us code which inserts data?

Comment: Relying exceptions will end up biting you regardless.  Do the queries and be done with it.

Comment: Gaps in autoincrement on failing inserts is given by design of your database engine. Here on SO are [many questions about it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=autoincrement+increase+failed+inserts).

Answer (score 0):

After failed transaction, your EntityManager gets locked – it's expected behavior. You can [reset it](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/2.8/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php#L245-L263) via:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->resetManager();
```

Comment: Won't help with the auto-inc problem which is kind of silly anyways.

Comment: @Cerad I suppose autoincrement is handled by database, so problem with it is not related to Doctrine EntityManager.

Comment: @Cerad also, using `int` as primary key is not always [good choice](https://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/).

Comment: getDoctrine() is not available at my context. How can I access to it?

Comment: @jkucharovic I agree.  Which is why I called it a silly requirement.

Comment: @ThiKool would you tell us what is yout context?

Comment: I got only the $this->getEntitymanager(); in my class (context) and $this-getEntityManger->resetManager(); is not available.